# Suppress an attribute for a single method at compile time?

Tags: c#, logging, postsharp

I'm using PostSharp, and I'd like to suppress (or change) an existing global attribute, for one method in the class.

In the example below, I want the class "thisIsLogged()" to be logged, and the class "thisIsNotLogged()" to not be logged.

However, it doesn't work: the attribute "[LogThis(false)]" simply *adds* to the existing class level attribute, and logging occurs anyway. Any ideas?

```
[LogThis(true)] // uses PostSharp + SmartInspect to switch on logging for the entire class
class doSomething
{
  void thisIsLogged(int x)
  {
     // entry/exit from this class is automatically logged
  }
  [LogThis(false)] // aim: suppress logging for this method, if [LogThis(true)] is switched on for the entire class (however, this doesn't work as attributes are additive)
  void thisIsNotLogged(int x)
  {
     // I want to suppress the entry/exit logging for this class, to reduce log size
     // However, this *doesnt work*; logging occurs anyway
     // as attributes are additive - any ideas?
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Used [LogThis(AttributeExclude=true)], this worked fine (see solution below).

Comment: Can you not simply remove the attribute?

Comment: Nope - if you remove the attribute from the class, then you have to add it individually to all 100 submethods by hand, and all classes that inherit from the base. If you apply the attribute to the class, its applied to all methods in the class by default which is much easier. Fortunately, you can suppress the attribute for an individual method or two, on demand (see below).

Comment: On a related note, feel free to try the ready-to-use SmartInspect PostSharp aspects: http://code.gurock.com/p/smartinspect-postsharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [MethodPointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397280/suppressing-postsharp-multicast-with-attribute), as Gael kindly suggested I use when I had a similar question.  This gives you a lot of flexibility to decide which methods to augment with aspects, including inspection of Attributes.

Comment: I also discovered another easy method: just use "[LogThis(AttributeExclude=true)]" to suppress the attributes for a particular method. Once you add this, it will even update the MSVS GUI to remove the underline indicating which attributes are attached to the method.